# How to edit json files (delete Objects / replace values)?

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a bunch of JSON files (metadata for my nft collection)
what I am trying to do :

- remove dna section from all files
- remove null values

The process:

1. read and parse all these files
2. make edits and write it in the same file

```json
{
  "dna": "xxxxxxxxxxx", #Delete this line from all
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "xxxx",
      "max_value": null  # delete null values
    }
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this will point you in the right direction:

```
import json

d = json.load(fp)
for key in [x for x in d.keys() if x != 'dna' and d[x] != None]:
 value = d[key]
 print(key,value)
```

Comment: how to read all files / how to do this for all files

Comment: you can use it in conjunction with  `os.listdir(folder)`

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have loaded your json into `nft` with

```
with open('<filename>', 'r') as f:
    nft = json.load(f)
```

You can delete them using `dict.pop(key: Hashable)` like so

```
nft.pop('dna')
if nft.get('attributes'):
    for attrs in nft.get('attributes'):
        keys = []
        for key in attrs:
            if attrs[key] is None:
                # attrs.pop(key)
                keys.append(key)
        for key in keys:
            attrs.pop(key)

print(nft)  # {'attributes': [{'trait_type': 'xxxx'}]}
```

Comment: thank you so much , but how to read all files and save changes for them in the same file